# Java NASA Worldwind Polygon with Internal Border

Tags: java, opengl, worldwind

So im aiming to make a system where you draw a surface polygon and it essentially makes a dashed border around the polygon. The issue is I want this border to be a set size, meaning each dash should be a set size around the polygon. Also Im working on trying to figure out how to make it so that if you increase the border size of a surface polygon that it will not expand outwards, only inwards, this way dimensions are skewed.

Long story short I started essentially calculating my own dashed border and drawing each dash by hand. The problem with this comes in at the angles where they meet and chopping off extra length when a dash would extend outside of the polygon. The picture attached shows what I have so far and what its essentially supposed to look like. I also sort of want to keep the normal border on the polygon the way it is in the picture, but that is not mandatory.

I guess i'm just surprised this is so hard to do in NASA Worldwind where in directX is was about 20 lines. This makes me think I'm going about it the wrong way.

Just as a note. I looked into using stencil buffers, but this proved to be almost a waste of time to get working and to run correctly through world wind. I dont think I have enough of a grasp to do this correctly.

P.S. None of the things I have started using are set in stone. I just need the final outcome to be correct. Thanks for the help.

[image: What I have so far with drawing each polygon of the border.]

TLDR: Need a to draw Polygons with an internal border of set width.

Comment: You can certainly do this in a geometry shader, spitting out both the triangle itself and the thick lined border.  However that's quite advanced.  All line drawing libraries have to consider mitre, round, bevel, etc. at joins.  This is a non-trivial subject.  Probably too much for SO to answer.

Comment: Could you point me in a direction of where I could find more info on geometry shaders? I'm surprised making a simple border is so hard.

Comment: There are lots of tuts out there.  Google for "geometry shader+opengl" and maybe "geometry shader+thick lines+opengl".

Comment: Currently i'm using the built in surface polygon and feeding it a list of points. The user currently just clicks points. They are polygons. So it could be a convex polygon or it could be a triangle depending how you draw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first to draw the (green) area, and second to draw a dashed (white) line.
When drawing the line, a [Geometry Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) can be used to convert the line segments to quads (triangle stripes with 4 points), which enclose the thin region, which would be filled by a solid line, in the given line thickness. The fragment shader finnaly has to dash the line (cut parts of the line). Finally the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) has to generate the dashed line (cut parts out of the line).

To draw the line, the [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type `GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY` has to be used (see [GLSL Tutorial - Primitive Assembly](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/primitive-assembly/)), because each line segment has to *know* its predecessor and successor, to calculate the angle bisectors in the corners. If a polygon is defined by a list of lines, that can be done easily. The last point of the list must be added at the beginning of the list of points and the first point of the list must be added at the end of the list of points.

e.g. If a polygon consist of the points *A*, *B*, *C* and *D*, then the list of points for the `GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY` would be *D*, *A*, *B*, *C*, *D* and *A*. This would give the following 4 line segments:

- *A* to *B*, with predecessor *D* and successor *C*
- *B* to *C*, with predecessor *A* and successor *D*
- *C* to *D*, with predecessor *B* and successor *A*
- *D* to *A*, with predecessor *C* and successor *B*

The [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) just has to pass through the corner points of the polygon:

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;

out TVertexData
{
    out vec3 pos;
} outData;

void main()
{
    outData.pos = inPos;
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
}
```

The [Geometry Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader) calculate the angle bisectors at the start end at the end of each line segment and generates a quad according to the thickness of the line.
Since the fragment shader still needs to generate the dashed line, the length of the line and the center of the line are calculated and passed to the fragment shader.

```
#version 400

layout( lines_adjacency ) in;
layout( triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4 ) out;

in TVertexData
{
    vec3 pos;
} inData[];

out TGeometryData
{
    vec3  linePos;
    vec3  lineMidPoint;
    float lineLen;
} outData;

uniform float u_thickness;

void main()
{
    if ( gl_InvocationID != 0 )
        return;

    vec3 pos0    = inData[1].pos;
    vec3 pos1    = inData[2].pos;
    vec3 dirPred = normalize( inData[0].pos - pos0 );
    vec3 dirSucc = normalize( inData[3].pos - pos1 );
    vec3 dirLine = normalize( pos1 - pos0 ); 
    vec3 dirNorm = normalize( dirPred - dirLine * dot(dirLine, dirPred) );
    dirSucc = faceforward( dirSucc, -dirNorm, dirSucc );

    vec3 dir0 = abs( dot(dirPred, dirLine) ) > 0.99 ? dirNorm : normalize( dirPred + dirLine );
    vec3 dir1 = abs( dot(dirSucc, dirLine) ) > 0.99 ? dirNorm : normalize( dirSucc - dirLine );

    vec3 pos01 = pos0 + dir0 * u_thickness / dot(dir0, dirNorm);
    vec3 pos11 = pos1 + dir1 * u_thickness / dot(dir1, dirNorm);

    vec3 lineMidPoint0 = (pos0 + pos1) * 0.5;
    vec3 lineMidPoint1 = lineMidPoint0 + dirNorm * u_thickness;

    outData.lineLen = length( pos1 - pos0 );

    outData.lineMidPoint = lineMidPoint0; 
    outData.linePos = pos0;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos0, 1.0); EmitVertex();
    outData.linePos = pos1;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos1, 1.0); EmitVertex();

    outData. lineMidPoint = lineMidPoint1; 
    outData.linePos = pos01;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos01, 1.0); EmitVertex();
    outData.linePos = pos11;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos11, 1.0); EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Finally the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) generates the dashed line by discarding fragments in the gaps.

```
#version 400

in TGeometryData
{
    vec3  linePos;
    vec3  lineMidPoint;
    float lineLen;
} inData;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform float u_dashLen;
uniform float u_gapLen;
uniform vec4  u_color;

void main()
{
    float midDist  = length( inData.linePos - inData.lineMidPoint ); 
    float modDist  = mod( midDist + u_dashLen * 0.5, u_dashLen + u_gapLen );
    float onDash   = max( step( modDist, u_dashLen ), 
                          step( inData.lineLen * 0.5 - u_dashLen, midDist ) );
    if ( onDash < 0.5 )
        discard;
    fragColor      = u_color * onDash;
}
```

Note, this [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) uses the `discard` keyword, to discard fragment which are in the gaps of the dashed line. If [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) would be used, then (`if ( onDash < 0.5 ) discard;`) could be omitted, because the fragments in the gaps would be drawn with an alpha channel of 0.

If the filled (green) polygon is drawn first, and the dashed (white) line is drawn second, then the result may look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much. Hate to even ask, but could you add how you called these from NASA world wind. Meaning how you apply a Shader to an Gl object.

Comment: So I have been setting this up in the existing code. I got the shader to activate, but it screws up the Globe because it seems like it is being applied to everything. How would I apply a shader to a certain renderable?